# JavaScript Error while calling function by JSNI

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, jsni

#### Exception caught: (TypeError):((intermediate value)(intermediate value),c).B is not a function

the JavaScript function like this:

```
A.prototype = {
    B: function() {
    },
    C: function() {
    }
};
```

the java function like this:

```
public final native void test()/*-{
    return this.B();
}-*/;
```

In my case, I can't edit the JavaScript file. So why this issue happend?

Comment: Sharing the rest of the class where the JSNI method `test()` can be found in will help us, along with showing how you are getting an instance of `A` in your java code, and how you are then calling `test()`/`B()` on it.

Comment: `$wnd.B()` and `$doc.B()` don't help me. The best way may be to fix the JS file.